# Copying html content using jquery is ignoring script in onclick

Tags: jquery

..how can I avoid this?

I'll give you a simple run down of what I am doing.

I am using this script below to copy code content of a specified div.

```
$("a.copy-code").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).each(function () {
    var linkId = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).zclip({
        path: '<?php bloginfo('
        template_url '); ?>/clipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: function () {
            return $('div[data-id=' + linkId + ']').html();
        }
    });
});
```

This all works great, with object tags and iframe tags etc.

But I am using the script above to copy content like this...

```
<div class="hide" data-id="copy-wb-small">
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.live.co.uk/?utm_source=' + window.location.host + '&amp;utm_medium=Web%20Badge&amp;utm_campaign=%2BLive%2B2013'); return false;"><img src="http://www.live.co.uk/assets/mcl-badge-100px.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

As you can see I have an onClick tag inside my anchor tag.

Now when I copy this, this is the result I get in the clipboard...

```
<a href="#" onclick=""><img src="http://www.live.co.uk/assets/mcl-badge-100px.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

It leaves out all my script. And the onClick is empty in the clipboard.

Can anyone advise if there is a function like `.html()` that will include scripts?

---

I created a fiddle with zclip and it works fine.

So it must be something to do with the output of the page.

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Ky/120/).

Comment: What about a jsFiddle?

Comment: Good idea - I will come back to it

Comment: jQuery seems to get the HTML just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/QdBrD/, must be something with zclip or the way you're using the HTML later?

Comment: @adeneo thank you for testing that fiddle for me. I then made a fiddle to test with zclip and it works fine! See here http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Ky/120/ . This is a bit confusing. The only thing I can think off is that the output from the wordpress page is changing it some how. Hmmm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: @adeneo figured it out thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

I guess wordpress the_content() php tag strips out all scripts from my html. So used wordpress code tag in my page which outputted the script as html.

Then just changed the code like this.

```
$("a.copy-code").on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).each(function () {
  var linkId = $(this).attr("id");
  $(this).zclip({
    path: 'http://secure.fbapps.co.uk/dev/clipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function() {
        return $('code[data-id='+linkId+']').html();
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Ky/121/